# PC freezing while training a neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

im having some issues while training whit tensorflow on python(on ubuntu 18.04), the main problem is that when i start to training all the gui start to freeze, sometimes i can play a video on youtube but in 144p not even 480p, now the question here is should i get another gpu? my actual gpu is a rtx2060, or it would be better to get an APU?(my actual cpu is an fx8320) im asking this question because soon i will change my cpu, and im not shure if i should get an ryzen 7 3800x and an small gpu like gtx1030 or by the other hand i should buy an 2400g, sell my 2060 and get an 2070 super, any advice would be great!

Comment: Although this question is too broad to answer in my opinion,you can check on online computing services for faster calculations to eliminate the need of buying new hardware to an extent. An example could be Google Colab...

Comment: What if your code gets stuck in some infinite loop?

Comment: i also use this pc for gaming and another tasks, my old 8320 is giving the best but actually i need to update jeje, about the online services, in sometime i will migrate to amazon but im planing to use it for commercial ends, this is more for self-learning stuff

Comment: FailingCoder what do you mean? is there a way to know if this is my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can explore : Intel movidius

https://www.movidius.com/news/intel-movidius-neural-compute-stick-honored-with-ces-best-of-innovation-award-2018

with out upgrading your system